# request failed with status code 500 with vue front end and thinkcmf backend

Tags: vue.js, http, nginx, thinkphp

when I request the login page with submitting it was giving above title error.

I write invalid username and password it says invalid username or password but if I enter valid credentials above title error pops up.

Error: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Kindly go to browser>inspect>Network>Response>check for error.

An error was: "Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated"

So I was using PHP version 7.4 than 7.2 so I change the {} to [] and save and reload.

the issue is solved.